# Questions about multiple particles 「は」and 「を」and interpunct in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-を, manga, punctuation

Here is the sentence.

左ジャブと右ストレートのワンツーを覚えた矢吹丈は、力石徹**を**殴り倒すことだけ**を**目的に地獄の中で生き抜くのですが、改めて読んでみて、これほど面白く・感動的な物語り**は**そう滅多に**は**ないと、僕は思いました。

Note: This sentence is written vertically.

1. For the second bold 「を」, I am not sure which object and verb relate to it. If the verb is「改めて」, then what is the object?
2. For the both bold 「は」, does it still have the same meaning and be grammatically correct if I remove them both?
3. For the interpunct between the word 「面白く」and 「感動的」, what is the purpose to put it in the place?

Comment: I think the use of interpunct here is very similar to the use of slash in English.

Comment: I .. think the を you are asking about actually connects to 目的に, which can likely be thought of as an abbreviation of a verb form.  Maybe. The object is likely the whole noun phrase ending with こと and starting after the comma, nesting the first を.

Comment: 滅多にはない is "there are not so many mangas this fun and touching", while 滅多にない is "there are hardly such mangas".

Answer (score 2):

1. を in を目的に indicate a object for 目的, it is 力石徹を殴り倒すことだけ in this case.
2. I think first and second は are a topic maker and third one is emphasis. You can remove the emphasis は and first は but you had better not to remove second は.
3. I don't know the reason. I think it is no problem it is comma.

Comment: Regarding to the question 1, does the verb 「改めて」relate to the  particle 「を」 in 「を目的に」?

Comment: No, this を doesn't relate to　改めて. The object of 改めて読んでみて is this manga but it is omitted in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

1. 〇〇を目的に（して）〇〇する. The して is often omitted. This is just a variant of the very common ＡをＢにする pattern.
2. You can't remove both; the basic clause is 物語りはない where は is the negative collocating version for contrast (there are many types of stories, but few such as *this*). The second one can be removed without changing the meaning much; it just adds a little extra emphasis.
3. Like WeirdlyCheezy said, it's more or less like using a "/" in English. That is, the story is both 面白い and/or 感動的 (perhaps the author can't himself decide which is best to use to describe his feelings?).